# Transform a string that is in a cell, into an array of ranges of rows and columns, some way?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I intend to transform these names from the list, in a range matrix like this shown in the image, when debugging the formula I want it to show me exactly an array of ranges of rows and columns, is there any way to transform these names into a range like This one??[image]

Comment: To what end?  Seems like Text to Columns will give you the end result you are looking for.

Comment: Do you want the text string or do you want to actually return an array that you use somewhere else?

Comment: Yes but if I used this option I would need an auxiliary column and if it is to use auxiliary columns it is better to use this formula: =TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A234);" ";REPT(" ";999));(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A234)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A234);" ";""))+1))-1)*999+1;999))

Comment: The problem with this formula is that it accepts only 33 spaces within the string, if it exceeds 33 spaces (" "), it gives an error. Is there any way for it to support more spaces

Comment: Is your desired end result exactly the array you are showing?  Or is it something else?  If something else, please show a screenshot of exactly what you really want.

Comment: Yes! A234 = "Jonh", B234 = "MAX", A235 = "James". and so on

Comment: I want it to turn into an interval like that there

Comment: That seems like the output of text to columns.

Comment: Yes, but I want to do with formulas, I really like using formulas for everything in Excel, prefer my own

Comment: It is not possible, with formulas, to have results in the same cells as your data, as you indicate you want in your comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the text string then use:

```
="={"""&TEXTJOIN(""",""",,SUBSTITUTE($A$2:$A$5," ","""/""")) & """}"
```

If you want an actual array that will be used somewhere else then use:

```
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRANSPOSE($A$2:$A$5)," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&ROW($A$1:$A$4)&"]"),"")
```

This will create a 4x4 array that can be used in other formula.  Depending on one's version, using this in another formula will need the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode to force the array formula.

I am not aware of any way to do what you want with `F9` and show the array in the formula bar.

Comment: I intend to bring a matrix, each name in each cell. I'm going to test your formula here

Comment: This last formula didn't work, she extracted only the first name: "Jonh"

Comment: Scott Craner, A234 = "Jonh", B234 = "MAX", A235 = "James". and so on

Comment: Highlight a box that is four cells by four cells.  Put the formula in the formula bar. Then hit ctrl-shift-enter

Comment: It almost worked, but I will consider it. However the name: "Max" was in the next row and was to be in the next column after the name "John"

Comment: Can you tell me where I find video lessons teaching how to use this "FilterXml ()" function ?? based on text extraction?

Comment: Then remove the transpose() wrapper on the range

Comment: the first time I see someone working with this "FilterXml ()" function, would I do it with another one?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the literal string, minus the typo "JONH" that I'm just not gonna replicate, can be gotten with Scott Craner's formula adjusted ever so slightly (and I used `SEQUENCE()` instead of the `ROWS()` trick, gotta use the new functions to get used to them, eh?), then used as the basis for some string work:

```
="={"""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(B234:B237),SEQUENCE(4)))&""","""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(C234:C237),SEQUENCE(4)))&""","""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(D234:D237),SEQUENCE(4)))&""","""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,INDEX(TRANSPOSE(E234:E237),SEQUENCE(4)))&"""}"
```

Bear in mind that while it gives the literal desired output, the output is **NOT** an array constant from Excel's perspective and will NOT get used by it precisely as the `F9` result would be.

It's just some text string for all Excel cares. So using it inside a formula will likely result in failure, or success by pure chance. Maybe it'd work right too, for some uses. But it is in no way the same or equivalent to Excel as the internal-usage array constant highlighting something and hitting `F9` creates.

That said, it's ugly and bloated. I don't follow the thread back and forth in the comments I guess, so I don't see why Scott Craner used `TRANSPOSE()` which forced me to as well since it seems the output desired is left-right (comment above with "A234 = "Jonh",...) so taking it out, then adjusting his A2:A5 to be A1:A4 (or drops a row for my experiments), I get:

```
=IFERROR(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(($A$234:$A$237)," ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b["&SEQUENCE(1,4)&"]"),"")
```

for his formula and re-working mine, then blending his in to use a single formula, I get:

="={"""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,B234:E234)&""","""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,B235:E235)&""","""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,B236:E236)&""","""&TEXTJOIN("""\""",,B237:E237)&"""}"

which, by the way, as it is patterned, repetitive in construction, one can use the old `CONCATENATE()` or `union operator` days tricks to build it out immensely with rows and columns adjusting nicely before finally concatenated, pasted special as the value, then an "=" placed before it to make it a formula. Even easier now. For data that isn't in four wee rows and less than five elements.

So then, that gives the expressed desired resultant string, though again, it is not a result Excel would see as being the same as the array constant you see after using `F9` as mentioned.

And the altered Scott Craner formula would then give the individual cell result described in the comment. Which could itself be used inside a formula to let Excel do the creating of that internal array constant. But NOT, I think, by using the string formula (which is a dead end, calculationally), but rather **using Scott Craner's (adjusted) formula inside whatever formula you need this in`so Excel will evaluate it to the desired`array constant**, and then, rather than filling these 16 cells, pass it up the calculation chain inside that formula.

Just realized it's "Scott Tenorman" (or close) in South Park, the one Cartman... gets revenge on... I'm no longer vaguely bothered by saying "Scott Craner" again and again!